# Filter and sort JSON formatted object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting

Lets say I've got an object in JSON format (like below) and I want to sort it by UserID

```
oUserColors = { "users": [
    { "UserID": 31, "Color": "Red" },
    { "UserID": 30, "Color": "Red" },
    { "UserID": 32, "Color": "Green" },
    { "UserID": 30, "Color": "Green" },
    { "UserID": 32, "Color": "Red" }
 ] };
```

I can easily use the following function to do so.

```
objSortedUserColors = oUserColors.users.sort(function (a, b) {
        return b.UserID - a.UserID; // sort oUserColors.users in descending order.
 });
```

which would give me this...

```
 objSortedUserColors = { "users": [
    { "UserID": 32, "Color": "Red" },
    { "UserID": 32, "Color": "Green" },
    { "UserID": 31, "Color": "Red" },
    { "UserID": 30, "Color": "Red" },
    { "UserID": 30, "Color": "Green" }
 ] };
```

But what if I want to also filter the object by color such that, if a user has both red and green as their color, the red gets removed and only the green remains. But if the user only has red as their color, it stays. Resulting in something like this...

```
 objFilteredSortedUserColors = { "users": [
    { "UserID": 32, "Color": "Green" },
    { "UserID": 31, "Color": "Red" },
    { "UserID": 30, "Color": "Green" }
 ] };
```

I'm stuck. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far that isn't working for you.

Comment: Most important tag is missing `javascript`. Secondly, it seems the sorting has nothing to do with your question... why even mention it?

Comment: "an object in JSON format" --- there is no such thing, it's just a JS object.

Comment: @trincot: Good point.I was originally thinking I could sort/filter in one go. It appears I should first sort, then filter..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know how to sort the array, I will just focus on the filter. You can use `reduce` for that and a helper object to maintain values keyed by UserUD. A Map would also work, but plain objects have an advantage of producing values in the order of increasing keys when they are non-negative integers.

```js
const oUserColors = { "users": [{ "UserID": 31, "Color": "Red" },{ "UserID": 30, "Color": "Red" },{ "UserID": 32, "Color": "Green" },{ "UserID": 30, "Color": "Green" },{ "UserID": 32, "Color": "Red" }]};

const result = Object.values(oUserColors.users.reduce( (acc, obj) => {
    const prev = acc[obj.UserID];
    if (!prev || prev.Color === 'Red') {
        acc[obj.UserID] = obj;
    }
    return acc;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```

The idea is to build an object (`acc`) with only the values of interest, keyed by UserID. If you find that during this collection there is no value yet for a UserID, you add it. If there is a value, and it has colour Red, then it is safe to replace it with the current object.

With `Object.values()` you convert that object back to an Array.

As it happens that JavaScript in all common browsers will produce the values in order of numerical key order (if non-negative integers), the output will be sorted.

Comment: Most helpful, sir! Much appreciated!